# How to get word after user input in textarea?

Tags: php, laravel, explode

I have a text area to user to insert text, but if the user type {{name}}, {{nickname}} and {{email}}. It must show the message with that value. Let me demonstrate:
For example: If user type: Hello, {{name}} has {{nickname}} and {{email}} the message must be like this: Hello, user A has nickname A and email@gmail.com.

This is my blade view:

```
// User insert text here
<textarea name="content" value=""></textarea>
```

My controller:

```
// My controller did not work, but I want to know how to use explode
$content = $request->input('content');
$new_content = explode($content, '{{name}}', '{{nickname}}', '{{email}}');
```

Comment: Textareas not allowed to add codes, so there is only one way to do that I think. Search for the word after “hello” and replace with what ever.  or compare words with stored email, name, nickname and replace it. Ajax can do real time searches.

Comment: You can't do that real-time with PHP as far as I know. Ask @Dlk suggested, that has to be handled on the front-end by a JS listener. The JS listener should hand-off the existing input as-is to an endpoint that processes and replaces the desired strings and handles the returned data updates to the content block you're using via AJAX requests.

Comment: use preg_replace to find and swap out those strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an approach I've used in a number of projects to allow template input and functions that return replacements.

here, $subject is the text being modified.

```
    preg_match_all('/{{(\S*)}}/',$subject,$matches,PREG_SET_ORDER);
    
    foreach($matches as $match) {
        $func = 'replace_'.$match[1];
        if(method_exists($this,$func)) {
            $subject = str_replace($match[0], $this->$func($match), $this->subject);
        }
    }
```

You can then create functions that start with `replace_` and return the string to be inserted in the original message

eg

```
public function replace_name($match)
{
  return $$this->user->name;
}
```